# display hijri calendar using ummalqura mode javascript in the yii2 framewrok

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, yii, datepicker, yii2

I'm trying to add Hijri calendar to my yii2 web application,I got this resource on Github HIJRI CALENDAR and i do as it said https://github.com/balbarak/bootstrap-hijri-datepicker

But when my App starts the calendar doesent displayed!
this is my code in the AppAsset.php file :

AppAsset.php :

```
public $css = [
    'https://fontlibrary.org/face/droid-arabic-kufi',
    'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css',
    'https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/2.7.1/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.min.css',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.css',
    'css/main.css',
    'css/timeline.css',
    'css/site.css',
    'css/authentication.css',
    'css/color_skins.css',
    'css/rtl.css',
    'css/plugins/bootstrap-select.css',

 public $js = [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js',
    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'bundles/momentjs/moment.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/2.7.1/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.js',
    'js/app.js',
    'bundles/mainscripts.bundle.js',
    'bundles/vendorscripts.bundle.js',
    'bundles/dropzone.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js',
    //'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.min.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.plus.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.plus.min.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.plugin.min.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.picker.js',
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js',
    'http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.calendars.ummalqura-ar.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
```

App.js :

```
  //datepicker hijri
$("#hijri-date-input").hijriDatePicker(
    {
        hijri : true,
        format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
        hijriFormat: 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD',
    });
```

Form View :

```
<div class="input-group">
<?=  $form->field($model, 'birthdate')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'hijri-date-input'])->label(Yii::t('app', 'birthdate')) ?>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is your https://github.com/balbarak/bootstrap-hijri-datepicker/tree/master/src/js script source

Comment: in yii2 we put all the sources in the AppAsset.php file

Comment: and what do you mean by not working ? are there any errors on console are all the scripts loaded correctly ? and your call to `$("#hijri-date-input").hijriDatePicker()` should be inside a ready state. how and where are you calling the datepicker, and ignore protocol when including an source from a cdn link the protocol will be assigned automatically just use the url like `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js`